# Retrieving neo4j nodes related to a given node using scala

Tags: scala, neo4j

I have 2 nodes named User_node and Article_node which are related by the relation

> article_node --> "Written_By" --> user_node

How do i get all the article nodes that are written by a given user node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the embedded neo4j and thus have an object of type `org.neo4j.graphdb.Node`. `Node` has the method `getRelationships` with several overloads, but the one that takes varargs of `RelationshipType` should work for you. To get all the `Node` objects connected to your starting node, you would have to write something like this (not tested):

```
// we use scala, so let's make our code pretty ;-)
import collection.JavaConverters._

val author = db.getNodeById(nodeId)

// getRelationships returns an Iterable[Relationship]
val rels = author.getRelationships(DynamicRelationshipType.withName("Written_By"))

// get the article node from the Relationship object
val articles = rels.asScala.map(_.getOtherNode(author))
```